# In Mongo - how to remove from a nested array with a specific id

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

This is my mongo collection

```
const cl = [{
  id: '601ad0d7afe0642f781f7794',
  history: [{
    _id: '601ad0d7afe0642f781f7795'
  }, {
    _id: '601ad0d7afe0642f781f7796'
  }]
}];
```

I want to remove the item in history with id: '601ad0d7afe0642f781f7795'

**This method is not removing the item.**

```js
cl.updateOne(
  { 'history._id': '601ad0d7afe0642f781f7795' },
  {
    $pull: {
      history: {
        _id: '601ad0d7afe0642f781f7795'
      }
    }
  }
);
```

**Have also tried but also isn't removing the item.**

```js
cl.updateOne(
  { 'history._id': '601ad0d7afe0642f781f7795' },
  {
    $pull: {
      history: {
        _id: {
          '$in': ['601ad0d7afe0642f781f7795']
        }
      }
    }
  }
);
```

Can anyone advise what I'm missing?

Comment: first try should work see [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Cws-3xc6Ohg) and make sure _id is in string in collection, if its objectId then convert using `_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId("601ad0d7afe0642f781f7795")`

Comment: @turivishal Yes you are right. I had wrapped it in an ObjectId when it should instead have been a string of an objectid.